# MySQL query optimization - 1 query vs 2 queries

Tags: mysql, optimization

I got into an argument with a professor today when we ran into the following problem. Say we want to build a movie quiz, where each question is a "Choose from four answers..." type of game. We then build our questions based on information queried from our database. One of the questions reads as follows:

```
Who directed the movie X...?
```

We would then query the database from our Movies table, that is described as follows

```
Field       Type            Null    Key Default     Extra
id          int(11)         NO      PRI NULL        auto_increment
title       varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
year        int(11)         NO      NULL    
director    varchar(100)    NO      NULL    
banner_url  varchar(200)    YES     NULL    
trailer_url varchar(200)    YES     NULL
```

Now, here's where my question lies. In my mind, I believe should be able to query the DB once, and limit our request to produce 4 results. From these 4 answers, randomly select one to be the correct answer, while the other 3 are the incorrect answers **(NOTE this would be done offline)**

Here was the query I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, director
FROM movies
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4;
```

However, my professor argued that the two SQL keywords `DISTINCT` and `LIMIT` are NOT safe enough to prevent us from getting possible duplicates. Further more, he brought up the edge case of "What if we only had one director in our movies table....?" And therefore concluded that we must use two queries; the first to get our correct answer, and the second query to get our incorrect answer.

If we could guarantee our table has more than one director, thereby eliminating the edge case my professor presented, wouldn't my query produce successful results every time? I've ran the query about 10-20 times, each one producing the exact results of what I wanted. Therefore, I'm struggling to find further evidence to pick the 2 query approach over the 1 query.

**EDIT -** I believe my question may have failed to address the point. The two answers are relying on the movie title being known prior to our query. However, we are not sure what movie will fill the question "Who directed ..?"  I was hoping to query the DB for 4 random results, then pick from the 4 random results on the Java side of our code to decide the "correct" answer, insert said movie's title into the question, and produce the 4 possible answers to the question.

Comment: You randomly assign correct answers? This is a very strange quiz !?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT title, director, CASE WHEN title = :title THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As isAnswer
FROM movies
GROUP BY title, director
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN title = :title THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    RAND()
LIMIT 4;
```

And remember that the first row is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your professor is partially correct on this... Your query in itself may coincidentally work, but that is probably based on a small sample of movies and is getting the movie in its result set.  So, take for example, you have 1000 movies and 47 directors, and the one movie "X" you have chosen, that director only made 3 of the 1000 movies in the list...  How realistic will your result set of directors be sure you have that director in question...

Sha's answer is very close in that it guarantees 4 results, but floating the director of movie "X" to the top, but that version has extra stuff not applicable.  You only want director's names, not what movies they did.  Then you would order that result by rand() to ensure the final order is randomized.

```
select
      pq.*
   from
      ( select 
              m.director,
              max( case when m.title = cTitleOfMovieYouWant then 1 else 0 end ) 
                 as FinalAnswer
           from 
              movies m
           group by
              m.director
           order by 
              max( case when m.title = cTitleOfMovieYouWant then 1 else 0 end ) DESC,
              RAND()
           limit
              4 ) pq
   order by 
      RAND()
```

So, the inner query only cares about a director, and a flag if they were the director or not of the movie in question.  The MAX( case/when ) is important because what if Director "Joe" directed 5 movies, only one of which was the movie desired.  You would not want Joe to appear once as the valid director, and once as not the director.  So, for the 1 movie, the flag will get set to 1, all the other movies that are NOT "X" will have flag of 0, so we want to keep the overall flag for the director as 1.

Now, since only one director for a given movie, the order by the same MAX( case/when) is in DESCENDING order, it will force this director to the top of the list, and then random for all others.

Once that result of 4 records is returned, the outer query runs that and orders IT by RAND() thus changing the final order.

Comment: I believe my question may have failed to address the point. Prior to our query, we are not sure what movie will fill the question "Who directed <movie_title>..?"  I was hoping to query the DB for 4 random results, then pick from the 4 random results on the Java side of our code to decide the "correct" answer, insert said movie's title into the question, and produce the 4 possible answers to the question.

Comment: @LeoVannini, yup... unclear in what you want, but if the "X" was known, then my query WOULD get what you need.  If you are going to have a pre-question of pick one of the following movies.... THEN ask who directed the movie selected, you would be good with my query.  But again, if you pick 4 random result directors, and one director made 30 movies, what's to stop from getting all 4 of that director's movies in the random result... nothing and all answers would  then be correct.  You would need to query for NOT the director for those movies.

Answer (score 0):

It gets messy because one director may direct multiple titles.

Try these two steps:

```
SELECT @correct := director FROM movies WHERE title = :title; -- first get corret answer

( SELECT DISTINCT director
    FROM movies
    WHERE director != @correct
    ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 3 )   -- 3 other directors
UNION ALL
( SELECT @correct )             -- and the correct answer
ORDER BY RAND();      -- shuffle the 4 answers
```

Within the big subquery:

1. `WHERE` is done entirely before...
2. `DISTINCT` happens before...
3. `ORDER BY` happens before...
4. `LIMIT`